AWS Cloudwatch event rule cron expression
I have this cloudwatch cron event rule to invoke a lambda function every 3 months on same dates (14th to 19th).  I want this expression to start running from the current month and 3 months from now and so on(june, Sep, Dec.. etc).  But it is starting to run from next month(july, oct, Jan.. etc).  How can I make this start running from the current month?


You cloud be more specific with months so instead of typing */3 you could type 6,9,12

This was a good work-around. Thanks.
